# Simple matrix derivative identity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, matrix-calculus

Is the following correct, and is there some kind of similar identity when $x$ and $y$ are matrices?

> For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\nabla_A x^T A y = x y^T$.

And my proof:

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{i j}} x^T A y = \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{i j}}
> \sum_{k_1 = 1}^n \sum_{k_2 = 1}^n x_{k_1} A_{k_1 k_2} y_{k_2} = x_i y_j$.

The motivation is the following identity which is also similar but not directly applicable:

> For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, C \in
> \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, $\nabla_A \text{tr} A B A^T C = C A B + C^T A B^T$.

Comment: FYI - Some people use `^\intercal` ($A^\intercal$) or `^\top` ($A^\top$) for the transpose. It looks much better than `^T`.

Answer (score 2):

By product rule you obtain the derivative (for any $H\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$)
\begin{align} 
D_A \operatorname{tr}(ABA^T C)[H] 
&= \operatorname{tr}(ABH^T C) + \operatorname{tr}(HBA^T C) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(H^T CAB) + \operatorname{tr}(BA^T C H) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(H^T CAB) + \operatorname{tr}(H C^T A B^T) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(H^T (CAB + C^T A B^T)).
\end{align}
Thus, $\nabla_A \operatorname{tr}(ABA^T C) = CAB + C^T A B^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $F(A)=x^TAy$. Observe that $F$ is linear with respect to $A$. Then 
$$
F'(A)H = x^T\ H \ y.
$$
The gradient of $F$ with respect to the inner produce $\langle A, B\rangle = tr(A^TB)$ is has to satisfy
$$
F'(A)H = \langle \nabla F(A),H\rangle.
$$
Now
$$
F'(A)H = x^TH y = \sum_{i,j=1}^n h_{ij} x_i y_j
=tr(H \cdot (xy^T)^T )
$$
which shows the desired identity $\nabla F(A) = xy^T$.